# Mailto link open in new tab only if web mail client

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page that creates a list of contacts and their email addresses.  You have two options for the mailto link, (1) open it in the current window or (2) open it in a new tab/window.

I see potential drawbacks from both sides:

- For web mail clients (e.g. gmail) option 1 is not ideal because it hijacks the window then, and the user must navigate back to the application in some fashion
- For desktop mail clients, the first option is not ideal because now you have a blank window/tab left open

Is there anyway to "detect" if the opened webpage has content and close it if not?

Based on this link:

[Detecting web-based mail client vs local mail client for a mailto link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837370/detecting-web-based-mail-client-vs-local-mail-client-for-a-mailto-link)

I tried the following to get the `body`:

```
const windowRef = window.open(`mailto:${email}`, '_blank')
const body = windowRef.document.body
```

The problem I was running into was that the `body` of each document was empty: `<body></body>`

I assume this was because it didn't have enough time to load the page, so I attempted to `setTimeout` but then I got a `Blocked a frame with origin "myhostman" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Any ideas on a way to support both web and desktop mail clients without the drawbacks listed above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty kludgy, but it *might* do what you need:

You can have a `SendEmail()` function defined like this:

```
function SendEmail() {
    const windowRef = window.open(`mailto:email@address.com`, '_blank');

  windowRef.focus();

  windowRef.onfocus = function() {
    return;
  } 

  setTimeout(function(){
    windowRef.close();
  },500);
}
```

and your `html` looks something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SendEmail();">email</a>
```

The idea behind this is that, if your user has a webmail as their default email client, then the `function` will just exit; however, if the user has a desktop email client, the new window will lose focus triggering the `setTimeout()` closing the new opened window.

My test works well using this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps9h455c/) *but* is "half" tested, I mean, since I don't have a webmail client set as my default client, I can't confirm this will actually work as you want, however I can confirm that the window closed when my desktop email client opened...

**UPDATE:**

Forget the function above, I slightly modified it to this:

```
function SendEmail() {
  const windowRef = window.open(`mailto:email@address.com`, '_blank');

  windowRef.focus();

  setTimeout(function(){
    if(!windowRef.document.hasFocus()) {
        windowRef.close();
    }
  }, 500);

}
```

I tested this in Firefox by setting Gmail and Yahoo! as my default email clients, and the new opened tab remained opened; then I changed it back to my desktop email client, and the new opened tab closed.  I did the same test using  Vivaldi, and IE Edge (where my desktop client is set as the default one), and the results were successfully the same.  Here's the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97naqavu/1/).

Comment: Creative idea you got there.

Comment: Interesting idea, and while I do also see the tab close for my desktop client, when testing with the web client, it also closes.

Comment: Bummer... okay, I have another idea.  I'll test it first, and if I succeed, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Tom Nolan I've updated my answer.  Hopefully that'll help.

Comment: Great solution, Vash. It can easily be modified to use an address passed from the link, and i put that change in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/perfectweb1/Lq8v84xh/